# Scala shapeless selection from HList of dependent types problem

Tags: scala, shapeless, singleton-type

I have a type dependent Cf type which stores singletoned string:

```
trait Cf {
  type Name <: String with Singleton
  def value: Name
}
object Cf {

  type Aux[A <: String with Singleton] = Cf { type Name = A }


  def apply(name: String): Aux[name.type] = { 
    val w = name.witness
    new Cf {
      override type Name = w.T
      override def value: Name = w.value
    }
  }
}
```

Imaging having another class Dbtest which only stores columns of some HList type:

```
class Dbtest[T <: HList](val columns: T)
```

Then I wanted to write some extension methods for my Cf type but there is one restiction: type of the instance on which extension method is going to be called have to be presented in HList of Dbtest instance :

```
object Ops {
  implicit class CfOps[C, N <: String with Singleton, T <: HList](ecf: C)
  (
    implicit 
      db: Dbtest[T]
    , ev: C =:= Cf.Aux[N]
    , selector: Selector[T, C]

  ) {

    private val cf = selector(db.columns)
    def simplePrint(): Unit = println(cf.value)

  }
}
```

Creating instances of Cf and Dbtest instance with some of them inside:

```
object Test extends App {
  val c = Cf("c")
  val b = Cf("b")
  val g = Cf("g")
  implicit val db = new Dbtest(c :: b :: HNil)
  ...
```

I want this to compile because `c` was specified in the HList:

```
 c.simplePrint()
```

And this not to compile because `g` is not presented in the HList:

```
g.simplePrint()
```

Main problem is - I cannot specify implicit Selector type correctly, so my `simplePrint()` method is not seen by the compiler:

```
value simplePrint is not a member of Cf{type Name = String("c")}
```

Is there a way I can specify selector type correctly?

Comment: Why do you need the `N` type parameter in `CfOps`? You don't use it. Also make sure `CfOps` is in (implicit) scope when you call the extension method.

Comment: @Jasper-M I use `N` only to be more specific in my evidence `ev: C =:= Cf.Aux[N]`, so I do not lose my inner `type Name`. `CfOps` is in scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to infer `N` in `CfOps(ecf)` for specific `ecf: C`, so `N` is just some abstract type and there is no implicit evidence `C =:= Cf.Aux[N]`.

Try to replace definition of `CfOps` with

```
implicit class CfOps[N <: String with Singleton, T <: HList](ecf: Cf.Aux[N])(
  implicit
  db: Dbtest[T],
  selector: Selector[T, Cf.Aux[N]]
) {
  private val cf = selector(db.columns)
  def simplePrint(): Unit = println(cf.value)
}
```

Then

```
import Ops._
c.simplePrint() // compiles
//g.simplePrint() // doesn't compile
```